# php basic form with txt file can't find directory

Tags: php

evryone. I'm trying to create a basic form to save just surname and lastname in a text file so when i will have to login i will retrive them from the txt file but apparently i'm doing something wrong with the directory for the txt file

now i updated the code and i'm having this secutity error

Warning: fopen(/home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/data/data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/form.php on line 66 Notice: Undefined index: fName in /home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/form.php on line 67 Notice: Undefined index: sName in /home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/form.php on line 67 Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/form.php on line 68 Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/form.php on line 76 !

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    echo "<a href = 'logout.php'>logout</a>";
    ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <body>
    <?php
    include ('includes/header.php');
    require_once 'includes/function.php';
    ?>
        <div class="nav">
            <?php
            include ('includes/menu.php');
            ?>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <?php include ('includes/footer.php');?>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $output ="";
    $form_is_submitted = false;
    $errors_detected = false;

    $clean = array();
    $errors = array();
    $nameArray = array();
    if(isset($_POST['SUBmit'])){
    $form_is_submitted = true;
    if (isset($_POST['fName'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['fName'])){
            $errors_detected = true;
            $errors = 'First name not entered';
            }else {
                if(ctype_alpha($_POST['fName'])){
                        $clean['fName'] = trim($_POST['fName']);
                    }else {
                        $errors_detected = true;
                        $errors = 'First name must contain alphabetical  letters only';
                    }
                }
            }
     if (isset($_POST['sName'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['sName'])){
            $errors_detected = true;
            $errors = 'Surname name not entered';
            }else {
                if(ctype_alpha($_POST['sName'])){
                        $clean['sName'] = trim($_POST['sName']);
                    }else {
                        $errors_detected = true;
                        $errors = 'Surname name must contain alphabetical letters only';
                    }
                }
            }


     }if($form_is_submitted === true && $errors_detected === false){
       $dir = '/home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/data';
if (is_dir($dir)){
    $handleDir = opendir('/home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/data');
    while(false !==($file = readdir($handleDir))){
        $path = "/home/sbau01/public_www/php/fma/data/".$file;
        if(is_file($path)){
            $handle =  fopen($path, 'a');
            $text = $clean['fName'].' '.$clean['sName']. PHP_EOL;
            $result = fwrite($handle, $text);
                if($result === false){
                    $formsErorrs = '<p>Oops! data not written</p>';
                }
                else{
                    $formsErorrs = '<p>Thank you for register with us. Yours details has been saved </p>';
                    $fullName = htmlentities($clean['fName']).' '.htmlentities($clean['sName']);
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
            else{
                $formsErorrs= '<p>Oops!!! file  has not been found >>>  '.$path.'</p>';
            }
        }closedir($handleDir);
        $output= '<p>Registration form has been submitted</p>';
    }else{
       $formsErorrs = '<p>Oops, the file has NOT been found!!!</p>'; 
    }
}
    else{
    $self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $formsErorrs = '';
    if($form_is_submitted === true){
        foreach($errors as $r){
            $formsErorrs = $formsErorrs .'<p>'.$r.'</p>';                   
        }   
    }
    if (isset($clean['fName'])) {
        $firstN = htmlentities($clean['fName']);
    } 
    else {
        $firstN = '';
    }
    if (isset($clean['sName'])) {
        $lastN = htmlentities($clean['sName']);
    } 
    else {
        $lastN = '';
    }
    $output = '<form action="'.$self.'" method="post">
        <fieldset>
                <table>

                    <tr>
                    <td><label for="fn">First Name</label></td>
                    <td>&#42; <input type="text" name="fname" id="fn"   value="'.$firstN.'" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><label for="ln">Last Name</label></td>
                    <td>&#42; <input type="text" name="lname" id="ln" value="'.$lastN.'" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="SUBmit" value="SUBMIT DATA" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form><p>&#32;</p>';
}
   echo make_heading('Registration Form',3);
    echo '<div id="breadcrumbs"> <a title="Back to home page"   href="index.php?">         Back to home page</a></div>';
   echo $output;
    echo $formsErorrs;
    ?>
```

Comment: why the 3 === when comparing a boolean?

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. Is students.txt a file, or a directory? From your code, it is a directory. Also, $file is a resource handler, but you're using it in $path as a string. It does not work that way.

Comment: so if i change form students.txt and put it in a folder let's say data/students.txt and then opendir('data/students.txt') and the same for $path?

Comment: No. For writing to files, you might want to use `file_put_contents()` or a combination of `fopen()` and `fput()`. It's better if you read the documentation on how to use these; there are some examples too. As for reading the file, you can use `file_get_contents()` or a combination of `fopen()` and `fread()`

Answer (score 0):

students.txt is not a directory.
I should change

```
$dir = 'students.txt';
if (is_dir($dir)){
```

to this

```
$file = 'students.txt';
if (is_file($file)){
```

Comment: ok, i change the code now is find the directory but it's not finding the file student.txt. i update the code on top

Comment: ok i update the code now i add the full path and is finding the file but i'm having this security error now